# Android Twitter Intent to my companies timeline

Tags: android

I am trying to open an Android intent to either go the mobile twitter site for my companies timeline or open actaul twitter application if installed.  I have it partially working, where it my phone asks how I would like to open the action (Browser, Twitter, etc..)  If I selected browser it goes to the mobile site fine.  If I selected Twitter I get "Unable to complete action" toast message.

`String url = "https://mobile.twitter.com/myCompanyTag";
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use twitter Web Intents: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents#follow-intent.
They are correctly processed by twitter official application.

The Url will be something like:
https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=luten87

Comment: Nice!  I was hitting my head at this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a non mobile url? The twitter app may not be expecting to parse a mobile url.

Additional resource that might help you..

http://omgwtfgames.com/2012/01/android-intents-captured-by-various-twitter-clients/

Comment: I tried the non mobile url and the http one instead of the https one with no luck.

Comment: Unfortunately this is fairly uncontrollable. It is what happens when companies do not define clear usage API's. You could always try sending an email to twitter and explain that they are making it extremely difficult to support their app by not providing clear methods of interaction.